# Delete Queue from bearerbox memory

Tags: sms-gateway, kannel

Today I faced a very strange issue.  I sent messages 10 days before and on that time `smpp` were in re-connecting mode. Today when `smpp` came online then messages are getting delivered. This shouldn't happen. Is there any parameter in `cannel` which can expire the message after a particular period of time.

I already used `validityperiod` parameter but it's not working for my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look on below issue number and find out it got solved or not.

https://kannel.org/issues/564